# Prove that the function $\varphi :\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that the function $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$
> \varphi(q) = 
> \begin{cases}
> -q & \text{if $q\leq 0$}\\
> q\sqrt{2} & \text{if $q\geq 0$}\\
> \end{cases}
> $$ is continuous.

If $-q$ is a rational number and and $q\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number. For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$. Then for $-q$ such that $|\varphi(q)-\varphi(c)|=|-q-(-c)|=|-q+c|=|\frac{q-c}{q+c}|\leq-|q-c|<\delta$ For $q\sqrt{2}$ such that$|\varphi(q)-\varphi(c)|=|q\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{2}|=\sqrt{2}|\frac{q-c}{q+c}|\leq\sqrt{2}|q-c|<\delta$. Therefore, $\varphi$ is contunious.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1) You will most likely have to treat the three cases $q>0$, $q=0$, $q<0$ separately.

2) As an example, for $q>0$, you must argue like this: Choose $\epsilon>0$. We must then choose $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0 < |x-q|  <\delta$ then $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(q)|<\epsilon$. Well, if $q>0$, we can always choose $\delta$ small enough so that $x$ will be positive as well; then
\begin{equation}
|\varphi(x)-\varphi(q)| = |x\sqrt{2}-q\sqrt{2}| = \sqrt{2}|x-q|.
\end{equation}
Then if $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(q)|<\epsilon$, we get $|x-q| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\epsilon$. So choose $\delta = \min\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\epsilon, \frac{1}{2}q\right)$. Working forwards again, if $|x-q|<\delta$, then from the definition of $\delta$ we see that $x>0$ so that $\varphi(x) = x\sqrt{2}$, and then
equation (1) holds so that $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(q)| < \sqrt{2}\delta \le \epsilon$. This shows that $\varphi$ is continuous at $q$.

Comment: I don't think you have to treat the three cases separately. For all $x,y\in\Bbb Q$, we have $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|\le 2|x-y|$, and from this it is easy to show continuity.